# How I can eliminate the date on the top right in a slide?

Tags: beamer

I use `Warsaw` theme but the date appear on the top right of each slide. 
How I can eliminate this date?

---

PREAMBLE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\useinnertheme{default}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usefonttheme{default}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip2pt}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,cmll}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{logreq}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please complete your code snippet until it becomes a complete document showing a typical frame exhibiting the problem, and remove the information that is not essential to the problem mentioned (surely most of all those loaded packages are not relevant here).

Comment: I tried to delete the packages one by one, and I find that the

Comment: the problematic package is "biblist".

Comment: \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{default}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblist}


\begin{document}

\title[Warsaw\_Date]{Warsaw\_Date}
\author[]{}
\institute[]{}
\date[]{}

\frame{
\titlepage
}

\frame{
\frametitle{Warsaw}
The date is hidden under the title `Warsaw'.
}

\frame{
Here the date is visible, like in the initial slide.
}

\end{document}

Comment: @pippigreco What isn't clear is *why* one should load `biblist` in a Beamer presentation: it's a package for "pretty printing" bibliography databases and has no use in a normal document.

Answer (score 6):

[`biblist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblist) defines an even/odd header by default. To remove this, redefine it after loading `biblist`:

```
\usepackage{biblist}% http://ctan.org/pkg/biblist
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{}% Formerly {\reset@font\rm \hfil \leftmark \quad (\today)}
\def\@evenhead{}% Forerly {\reset@font\rm (\today)\quad \ignorespaces \rightmark \hfil}
\makeatother
```

[image]